# Rolling mean with two column identifiers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with two column identifier `Date` and `ID` and try to calculate the rolling mean of the `Score` over three days for each `ID` individually over time.

```
Date        ID  Score
2022-01-02  1   1
2022-01-03  1   2
2022-01-04  1   1
2022-01-05  1   3
2022-01-02  2   5
2022-01-03  2   6
2022-01-04  2   7
2022-01-05  2   3
```

So far I only know how to create a rolling mean over one particular column without considering the second identifier `ID`:

```
df[RollingMean3]=df[Score].rolling(3).mean()
```

I try to get

```
Date        ID  Score  ScoreRollingMean3
2022-01-02  1   1      NaN
2022-01-03  1   2      NaN
2022-01-04  1   1      1.33
2022-01-05  1   3      2
2022-01-02  2   5      NaN
2022-01-03  2   6      NaN
2022-01-04  2   7      6
2022-01-05  2   3      5.33
```

For reproducability:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05'],
    'ID':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'Score':[1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3]})
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`Series.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) if datetimes are consecutive:

```
df['RollingMean3']=df.groupby('ID')['Score'].rolling(3).mean().droplevel(0)
print (df)
         Date  ID  Score  RollingMean3
0  2022-01-02   1      1           NaN
1  2022-01-03   1      2           NaN
2  2022-01-04   1      1      1.333333
3  2022-01-05   1      3      2.000000
4  2022-01-02   2      5           NaN
5  2022-01-03   2      6           NaN
6  2022-01-04   2      7      6.000000
7  2022-01-05   2      3      5.333333
```

General solution with rolling window `3D` is possible with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.set_index('Date')
df['RollingMean3']=df.groupby('ID')['Score'].rolling('3D').mean().droplevel(0)
print (df)
            ID  Score  RollingMean3
Date                               
2022-01-02   1      1      1.000000
2022-01-03   1      2      1.500000
2022-01-04   1      1      1.333333
2022-01-05   1      3      2.000000
2022-01-02   2      5      5.000000
2022-01-03   2      6      5.500000
2022-01-04   2      7      6.000000
2022-01-05   2      3      5.333333
```